# How do we calculate this exponential integral if we change limit from $\infty$ to $x_1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

We know the solutions of this integral *(Bronstein-Semendijajev mathematics manual [page474])*:

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}x^n \cdot e^{-ax^2}dx = \frac{1\cdot3\dots(2k-1)\,\,\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{k+1}a^{k+1/2}}\longleftarrow\substack{\text{$n$ is the exponent over $x$}\\\text{while $k=n/2$}}
\end{align}

But how do I calculate the integral if I change the upper limit from $\infty$ to $x_1$ which is constant - for example how do I calculate this integral:

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{x_1}x^2 \cdot e^{-ax^2}dx
\end{align}

Comment: One does not simply change the limit from ∞ to x_1

Comment: I din't change it. I have to solve the later integral which has $x_1$ for limit. But i found the first integral in the mathematics manual.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$I(a) = \int_0^{x_1} dx \, e^{-a x^2} = \frac12 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \text{erf}(\sqrt{a} x_1)$$

Then the integral in question is $-\partial I/\partial a$, which is

$$\frac14 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^3}} \text{erf}(\sqrt{a} x_1) -  e^{-a x_1^2} \frac{x_1}{2 a}$$

This may be used for even $n$, using successively higher derivatives with respect to $a$.  For odd $n$, you may rather use derivatives with respect to $a$ of the integral

$$\int_0^{x_1} dx \, x \, e^{-a x^2} = \frac12 \frac{1-e^{-a x_1^2}}{a}$$

Comment: Thank you. Is the error function really necessary :/ ???

Comment: @71GA: as far as I know, yes, no way around it I am afraid.

Comment: Does this mean this can only be solved using numerical methods?

Comment: @71GA: The error function is used so often that every math package has it built in.  Simple routines exist that compute its value to as many decimal places as you like with a few simple operations.  So, do you need numerical integration?  Heaven's no!  It's like having a Bessel function - actually, even easier.

Comment: Well my calculator lacks it :)

Comment: @71GA: what can your calculator do?  Is it programmable?  Does it have statistical functions (i.e., cumulative of normal random variable)?

Comment: It doesn't even have a $\sinh$, $\cosh\dots$. It is not programable. Can you recommend any good calculator to calculate integrals?

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^{x_1}x^2e^{-ax^2}~dx$

$=\int_0^{x_1}x^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^nx^{2n}}{n!}dx$

$=\int_0^{x_1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^nx^{2n+2}}{n!}dx$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^nx^{2n+3}}{n!(2n+3)}\right]_0^{x_1}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^n{x_1}^{2n+3}}{n!(2n+3)}$